# Jquery Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Anyone can tell me why i am getting this error:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined**

```
function checkNewPost(x) {
        var pid = $('#NewPostbody').attr('class');
        if(pid === 'post-t') {
            setTimeout(checkNewPost, <?php echo $p_id; ?>);
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/html_postReply.php",
                data: "pid="+pid.replace('post-t', '')+"&type=1", 
                success: function(html) {
                    if(html) {
                        $('.tekin').append(html);
                        jQuery("span.timeago").timeago();
                        $(".tekin").scrollTop($(".tekin")[0].scrollHeight);
                    }
                    if(!x) {
                        setTimeout(checkNewPost, <?php echo $p_id; ?>);
                    }
               }
            });
        }
    }
    checkNewPost();
```

Comment: It just means that `pid` is `undefined`.

Comment: If you can use a fallback (e.g. the empty string), you can use the `||` operator: `var pid = $('#NewPostbody').attr('class') || '';`.

Comment: Would you be opposed if I edited your title and tags? This honestly doesn't have anything to do with jQuery. It's a standard JavaScript error message caused by an `undefined` value...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that this error is caused by one of two scenarios, based on the given information above:

1. `$('#NewPostBody)` is not being found in the DOM
2. `$('#NewPostBody)` is being found but has no class attribute.

This can be solved using the following method:

```
var pid = ($('#NewPostBody').length && $('#NewPostBody').attr('class')) 
    ? $('#NewPostBody').attr('class') 
    : "";
```

The ternary operator along with *truthy/falsy* logic should result in either the class being returned or an empty string. Either way, `pid.replace('post-t', '')` can safely be called without resulting in an error.

Comment: War10ck your answer solved my problem..I'm not clear understood plz give information about this answer.